# Apache2 Force redirect to HTTPS doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to set redirect of all trafic to HTTPS. But when I access http://example.com it gives "403 Forbidden" error. With HTTPS everything works good.

My `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` has everything by default except of:

```
<Directory /home/site/www>
        Options -Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

My `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf` looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin admin@example.com
        DocumentRoot /home/site/www
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /home/site/.ssl/example_com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/site/.ssl/example.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /home/site/.ssl/example_com.ca-bundle

        ErrorLog /home/site/www/errors.php
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

My `.htaccess` looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

The website is hosted on Ubuntu 16.04. on Google Cloud. The same setup but on Amazon AWS works good and rewrites all requests to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

Just had to `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf` and add:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /home/site/www
</VirtualHost>
```

to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/example.com.conf`